# How to prevent iFrame alert box

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

Is there a way to prevent alert box in iFrame even the domain in the iFrame was not mine?

Comment: You can't control anything inside an iframe if the domain is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not. Due to security reasons, you can't controll anything in iframe if the iframe source is from another domain.